# npm install dependency node-sass issue

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies

Let's say I have the project "my-project". This project depends on the package: "my-library".

The `package.json` of 'my-library' looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "###",
    "version": "1.1.2",
    "description": "###",
    "main": "./dist/index.js",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        ...
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        ...
        "node-sass": "^8.0.0"
        ...
    }
}
```

As you can see, the project only has `devDepedencies`, no `dependencies`.

Now when I try to install the library in "my-project", with `npm i git+https:/###` there is an error due to node-sass and the installation fails. If I start the command with `--ignore-scripts`, everything runs smoothly.

My problem is not that the installation of node-sass fails, I know it's deprecated.

My Question is: Why is does npm tries to install node-sass, although it's a devDependency of my dependency?

From my understanding, nothing related to node-sass should be run.

Here is what I've already tried:

- npm i --force (failure)
- npm cache clean --force (failure)
- Removing node_modules (failure)
- Freshly cloning the entire repo (failure)
- Switching node versions (tried with v16, v19, v21)
- `npm i <url> --force --ignore-scripts` (success)

Running `npm view <url>` gives the correct version and shows "deps:0", which is correct.